# I need to call a c++ function within a function using the same object?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading, data-hiding

Example:

```
class Person
{
private:
     int age;
public:
     int getAge()
     {
         return age;
     }
};
class Employee: public Person
{
private:
    int empNum;
};
```

Now say I want to overload the + operator to add the ages of two employee objects. One of those employee objects calls the overloaded operator function, but in this instance, I also need that object to call the getAge() function from the base class.  I know I could just make age protected instead of private, but is there a way to do this leaving that property private?

Comment: `getAge()` is already public so there's no problem.

Comment: What's the problem with `int operator+(Person& a, Person& b) { return a.getAge() + b.getAge(); }`?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I wouldn't recommend such an overloading. Is it really 'obvious' that person + person equals a person with the sum of their ages? Why so? Why not the weight or anything else :-) Operator overloading should be used very judiciously. `a.getAge() + b.getAge()`, or `sumAge(a,b)` .. I'd stick with one of those.

Comment: @elmes To some extent, I agree with you, but this is largely a matter of style and the original poster did explicitly ask for an overloading of `operator+` to add the ages.

Comment: I used the people's ages, because I thought it was easier to look at than what I'm actually doing.  It was for simplification.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to write your operator like this:

```
int operator+(const Employee& arg1, const Employee& arg2) {

  int result = arg1.getAge() + arg2.getAge();
  return result;

}
```

Comment: +1 - although I'd argue the operator should take `Person` objects rather than `Employee`s, even if that's not what the original poster asked for.

Comment: Do you not have to use a class to overload an operator?  I was under the impression that it had to be done in the class.

Comment: @Jerold Davis: No, You can do it outside of the class. A typical example is to provide a text representation of objects for output streams: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.8

Answer (score 0):

Simply: No.

You always need the method (or variable) to be protected or public to let you call it from a subclass. (Or you can define another "getter" method to access it, but now it must be protected or public.)

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the plus operator for Person. Alternatively, getAge() is callable from the overloaded operator, since it's public.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave that property private, you can use a friend operator overloaded function.

Comment: So, because it's a friend function, it has no this pointer, meaning it was not called by the object, I simply pass the two objects I want to operate on into the function, correct?